# Expand div height with interval

Tags: jquery, css, height

I'm working with a div that has a pattern-image as background. The pattern is repeatable but is preferred to expand with an interval of pixels.

I would like to know if there is a solution to expand a div with a fixed interval but still expand as text fills the div.

Say the pattern is best viewed with the interval of 10px, eg. height:120px, 130px, 140px etc.
A div is present with dynamic content and as the height of the div expands the height is fixed to the next possible height within the interval.
Eg. the original height of the div is 132px, which should be transformed into 140px automatically.

Is this possible? I've added the jquery tag since I assume this is not possible with CSS alone and javascript/jquery is my guess for a solution :)

**SOLUTION:**

I combined a solution of the two existing answers:

```
$(function(){
    var DivSize = function(el) {
        $(el).css('height',Math.ceil( $(el).height() / 10 ) * 10+'px');
    }
    DivSize("#test");
});
```

This seems to do the job!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the existing solutions is that they don't take into consideration that you're setting a static height on a div which will then not change no matter what the content is. So you will need an element to tell you want the content height is, then the wrapping element holds the background and is expanded according to the height changes in the inner content.

This jsFiddle example should speak for itself, the interval is ofcourse for testing / demo as is the css.
http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/uHsVg/

The example JS:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var $inner = $('#innerContent'),
        $outer = $('#outerDiv');

    // Change the contents.... 
    $inner.text($inner.text() + ' lorem ipsum dolor sit amet');

    // Height changed over treshhold? treshhold = outerheight
    if ($outer.height() <= $inner.height()) {
        $outer.height(Math.ceil($inner.height() / 10) * 10);
    }

}, 250);
```

Example HTML:

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="innerContent">Test</div>
</div>
```

This expanding div doesn't need to be absolute or anything, it'll act like any normal html block element with a static height set to it.

**Edit**: to also make it shrink just remove the treshhold if statement, I just put that there so it would only set the height on a real change and not just *any* change...

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: I see your point and this solution could work in some cases, but not in mine as my div can differ with more than 100 pixels :(

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work if the element has padding or border (if it has, you need to account for those) and hasn't been tested.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(
    function(){
    var div = jQuery("#pattern-div"), curHeight = div.height();

    div.css( "height", Math.ceil( curHeight / 10 ) * 10 );

        window.setInterval(
            function(){

            var newHeight = div.height(), roundedHeight;

                if( newHeight !== curHeight ) {
                roundedHeight = Math.ceil( newHeight / 10 ) * 10;
                curHeight = roundedHeight;
                div.css( "height", roundedHeight );
                }

            },
        200 );
    }
);
```

It keeps checking if the automatic height has changed, ceils it up to nearest 10 and sets it as
the height.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I see, so you always want your div size to be a multiple of 10.

You should fire or call a function when the content is updated, then just set the div height to the next greatest multiple, something like:

```
function DivSize(el) { 
    $(el).css('height',$(el).height()+(10-$(el).height()%10)+'px');
}
```

Your div will beed to be position:absolute; or :relative; for height() to work.

Comment: Hmm.. I see the idea and Im trying it right now.
If i set height of the div eg. 83px it will fix it to 86 instead.
If i set height to 85px it will fix it to 90..

Almost working.. I just dont know how to fix it

Comment: Oops, try 'height',$(el).height()+(10-$(el).height()%10)+'px'); The %10 means "mod 10" or "the remainder of the number divided by 10), so the change in div height needs to be 10-remainder.